# Apache flink - Time characterstics

Tags: apache-flink, stream-processing

How can i use the Ingestion time characteristics in Apache flink. I know we need to set the environment time characteristics. But how can i collect the data with timestamps which can be referred as ingestion time. Currently when i am using it, it is processing the window based on system clock time. I want to do the processing based on the time at which data enters the flink environment.

A little code extract which may help to understand it clearly :

Time characteristics for environment :

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);
```

Window time :

```
keyedEvents.timeWindow(Time.minutes(5))
```

Collection in source  :

```
ctx.collect(monSourceData);
```

If the data collection starts at let say 11:03, I want to end it at 11:08 i.e. for 5 minutes. But it stops at 11:05 ( somehow behaving like processing time ).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Tumbling and sliding windows in Flink are always aligned to the clock (either the event time clock defined by the events and watermarks, or the system clock); time windows are not aligned to first event. So if you have windows that are 5 minutes long, there will be a window for the interval from 11:00 to 11:05, for example, regardless of the TimeCharacteristic.

Tumbling windows do, however, take an optional *offset* parameter that can be used to shift this alignment. So you could specify `TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5), Time.minutes(3))`, for example to shift the intervals by 3 minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Is there any possibility to run windows based on first event, if i get the first event/data entity at 11:03 the window should run for "n" minutes, as i mentioned in the example given in question.

Comment: I can't think of any way to accomplish that using the Window API, but you could build it yourself using a ProcessFunction.

Comment: I don't get it, as per my knowledge process function execute as soon as window ends, so we need to customize window time somehow. Also i guess trigger can be useful in this scenario. But as I have just started learning flink, if you can help me with any kind of code snippet or logic that would be pretty awesome. Thanks

Comment: I mean to say that you could use a process function instead of a window.

Comment: Thank you so much David for your help. :)

Comment: I read the documentation about process function, but i couldn't implement it the way i want to.. as i said in above example. Could you please explain it in layman terms, that would be a great help. ( some psuedo code too if possible ). Thanks

Comment: You're right; I tried to write the code, and it's not as straightforward I'd imagined. So far the only solution I see is fairly complex -- are you sure you need to solve this problem? :) What makes it difficult is if you want to do keyed windowing, in parallel, and have everyone agree on the starting timestamp.

Comment: What you could do would be to split the stream before it is keyed. Send one side of the split into a RIchFlatMap that grabs the timestamp of the first event, and broadcasts that into a  KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction that does the windowing using timers that fire every five minutes starting from that broadcast timestamp.

Comment: Yes, I surely need to solve that problem. But the issue is I am not very much familiar with flink. So, any kind of help/hint from your side would be great.

Comment: See https://training.data-artisans.com/ for training materials that show how to work with process functions, broadcast state, timers, etc.

Comment: Thanks David.. I will check them, will try to implement it and tell if I get success or will disturb you again. :)